# How to get the image history from a private docker-registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a private docker registry that is growing and consuming all the disk space. Until now we increased the disk space two times but now we like to delete the images that haven't been accessed for a long time, how can we get the last time an imaged has been accessed? Is there an API call for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/better-programming/cleanup-your-docker-registry-ef0527673e3a

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#deleting-an-image

https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

Not exactly a browser of the registry giving you last access dates like you were looking for although you could look through the file tree manually to find those dates. I believe what you are asking (straightforward way to manage registry images) is still not directly supported by Docker.